# data exchange format to use with Apache Kakfa that provides schema validation

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, schema, avro

what is the best message format to use with apachhe kafka so that producers and consumers can define contract and validate data and serialize/deserialize data? for example in xml we have xsd. but in json there is no universal schema.. i read about using apache avro but not sure how fast will it be as i can't afford more then 5 to 6 ms for schema validation and deserialisation? any inputs please?
We will be  processing thousands of transactions per second and SLA for each transaction is 150ms so i am looking for something that's very fast

Answer (score 1):

Avro is often quoted as being slow(er), and adds overhead compared to other binary formats, but I believe that is for the use-case of **not** using a Schema Registry where the schema is excluded from the actual payload.

Alternatively, you can use [Protobuf or Thrift](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html) if you absolutely want a schema, however, I don't think serializers for these formats are readily available, from what I've seen. Plus, the schemas need to be passed between your clients if not otherwise committed to a central location.

I can confidently say that Avro should be fine for starting out, though, and the Registry is definitely useful, and not just for Kafka use cases.